# How to track outgoing email in drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, mass-emails

I am using Views send module (https://www.drupal.org/project/views_send) to send email through drupal. But is there any module to track email, who open it, when it open, how many times it open etc ?

Answer (score 0):

No. An email is personal. If we knew if someone did or didn't/read our work emails it would be a lot more like Facebook. Which would be problematic especially for businesses IMO.

quote from easykey.uk on google:

> There is no reliable method to check whether an email has been read.
>   If you would like a person to confirm
>   receipt of an email – ask them in your email message.

If you want to log your emails that are sent from drupal you can either use

[Maillog](https://www.drupal.org/project/maillog) or [email log](https://www.drupal.org/project/emaillog) or you could query the database for the watchdog table.

You need to provide your users you email with a *Call to Action* inside the email and handle the responses accordingly, that way you will know which users have successfully engaged with your email.

The other data you want such as *who opened it?*, *How many times it was opened?*,  have to just hash it out as **successfully sent emails**, anything past that is pretty much out of scope.